# How do you run SOAP UI test suite with Commandline tool like Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, soapui

I am new to soap ui and Jenkins

1. how do you run soap ui test suites using Jenkins?
2. how do you generate reports in soap ui?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think below link has all the information you need

http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/functional-tests.html

Jenkins is actually a continuous integration tool. Once you are able to invoke SOAP UI via Command line, then you can use jenkins to run your tests periodically in the remote machines you have configured.

Answer (score 1):

Forget going to SoapUI documentation to get it working.  You'll get it done much faster by just looking at [the sample project I put together](https://github.com/djangofan/soapui-maven-template).

Just remember, there are 2 different versions of the SoapUI plugin, a free one created by a guy on Github and the official one.  They both work similarly.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a *"testrunner.bat"* script in the installation directory of SOAP UI. This script handles many different arguments to customize the test execution. The most important are:

- -s is used to specify the TestSuite to run
- -c specifies the TestCase to run
- -f specifies the root folder where the test results will be saved
- -M creates a test run log file in xml format
- -r prints a small report summary
- The last parameter is the path to the SOAP UI project file you want to use

If you own the **SOAP UI Pro** (now called ReadyAPI) license you can use -R and -F to specify a report and its format to be generated. Here is an example:

> testrunner.bat -FHTML -R"Your Report" c:\soap-ui-repots\report.html

For Jenkins you could create your own script with the parameters you need and execute it after each build.