# Need instructions on config Jenkins (Linux) to call soapui tests email report to a group

Tags: jenkins, soapui

Need instructions on how to config Jenkins (Linux) to
1. call soapui tests on remote windows machine daily to run test 
2. email report to a group

thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you run SOAP UI test suite with Commandline tool like Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739277/how-do-you-run-soap-ui-test-suite-with-commandline-tool-like-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this scenario is given in the thread [How do you run SOAP UI test suite with Commandline tool like Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739277/how-do-you-run-soap-ui-test-suite-with-commandline-tool-like-jenkins) .

And also refer soapui.org website they explained in detail, First try it in local machine in SOAPUI by running testrunner.bat command line tool provided by SOAPUI.

Then go for jenkins to shcedule jobs to run SOAP UI projects / Testsuites using testrunner.bat.

In your case Jenkins running in Linux server and SOAPUI is in windows machine.

Follow the below steps to achieve it.

1. Install cygwin tool in windows machine - which provide you a virtual Unix environment in windows machine.
2. Configure your Jenkins server to windows machines as node [Here cygwin helps you to create ssh keys and you can do it just like adding node for Unix / Linux environment].
   Refer this https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Havemasterlaunchslaveagentviassh
3. Now create job in Jenkins.
4. In Configure-> Execute shell / Batch, run Loadrunner.bat with proper command line arguments.
5. Click Build Job in Jenkins.

Hope it helps you.

Thanks,
Madhan

Comment: thanks Madhan, I will try as you answered and let you know. thanks!